# Applying Julia function to nested array of arrays

Tags: arrays, nested, julia

Is there a simpler way to do apply a function in Julia to nested array than defining a new function? -  e.g. for this simple example:

```
a = collect(1:10)
b = [ a*i for i in 100:100:400]

arraylog(x) = log.(x) ## Need to define an extra function to do the inner array?
arraylog.(b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a comprehension just like you used it to define `b`: `[log.(x) for x in b]`.

The benefit of this approach is that such code should be easy to read later.

**EDIT**

Referring to the answer by Tasos actually a comprehension implicitly defines an anonymous function that is passed to `Base.Generator`. In this use case a comprehension and map should be largely equivalent.

I assumed that MR_MPI-BGC wanted to avoid defining an anonymous function.
If it were allowed one could also use a double broadcast like this:

```
(x->log.(x)).(b)
```

which is even shorer but I thought that it would not be very readable in comparison to a comprehension.

Comment: or even  `b .|> x->log.(x)`

Comment: Nice. Julia is really powerfully composable.

Answer (score 1):

You could define it as a lambda instead.

Obviously the distinction may be moot, depending on how you're using this later in your code, but if all you want is to not waste a line in your code for the sake of conciseness, you could easily dump this inside a `map` statement, for instance:

```
map( x->log.(x),  b )
```

or, if you prefer `do` syntax:

```
map(b) do x
  log.(x)
end
```

---

<sub>PS. I'm not familiar with a syntax which allows the broadcasted version of a function to be plugged directly into map, but if one exists it would be even cleaner than a lambda here ... but alas 'map( log., b )' is not valid syntax.</sub>